# add a column with customised results

Tags: r

Below is the dataset I have.

```
Name  Price  
A      3     
A      0.5
A      0.8   
A      0.1
A      0.1  
B      0.5
B      0.9
B      1 
B      0.4
B      5
```

I need a column that tells, if the sum of prices is more than 1, then retain as it is, or else, sum it to the next prices untill it reaches 1. I need the output like below

```
Name  Price   Result
A      3      3
A      0.5
A      0.8   1.3 #(Since the below price is 0.1 and 1.3+0.1 is 1.4, 
A      0.1        #can we set a limit)
A      0.1   0.2 
B      0.5
B      0.9   1.4
B      1     1
B      0.4   
B      5     5.4
```

Comment: Is there a natural sorting to the data?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way to solve this using R's vectorised methods but here is a traditional `for` loop

```
#Initialise values
df$Result <- NA   #to store results
sum_vec <- 0      #variable to store carry over values
is_full <- TRUE   #flag to check if there is a carryover from previous value

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) { #For each row of the dataframe
  if(df$Price[i] >= 1 & is_full) {  #if price is greater than 1 and no carryover
     df$Result[i] = df$Price[i] #assign current price to result
     is_full = TRUE #assign carryover as TRUE
  }
  else {
     sum_vec = sum_vec + df$Price[i] #Add previous value to current price
    if (sum_vec >= 1) { #If sum is greater than 1 add it to result
       df$Result[i] = sum_vec
       is_full = TRUE
      sum_vec = 0 #reassign carryover value to 0
    }
    else {
      df$Result[i] = NA #make current result as NA
      is_full = FALSE #keep carryover flag as FALSE
    }
 }
}

df
#   Name Price Result
#1     A   3.0    3.0
#2     A   0.5     NA
#3     A   0.8    1.3
#4     A   0.1     NA
#5     A   2.0    2.1
#6     B   0.5     NA
#7     B   0.9    1.4
#8     B   1.0    1.0
#9     B   0.4     NA
#10    B   5.0    5.4
```

---

For the updated example, we can `split` by groups (`Name`) and apply the same thing again

```
df$Result <- unlist(lapply(split(df$Price, df$Name), function(x) {
                  result <- numeric(length = length(x))
                  sum_vec <- 0    
                  is_full <- TRUE 
                  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
                     sum_vec = sum_vec + x[i]
                    if (sum_vec >= 1 | i ==length(x)) {
                       result[i] = sum_vec
                       is_full = TRUE
                       sum_vec = 0
                     }
                     else {
                      result[i] = NA 
                      is_full = FALSE 
                      }
                    }
                    result
                   }))

df
#   Name Price Result
#1     A   3.0    3.0
#2     A   0.5     NA
#3     A   0.8    1.3
#4     A   0.1     NA
#5     A   0.1    0.2
#6     B   0.5     NA
#7     B   0.9    1.4
#8     B   1.0    1.0
#9     B   0.4     NA
#10    B   5.0    5.4
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks and I got it. But Is it possible to take the Categories(Name) into account.  I have also edited the dataset, Aplogies for this. The code has to stop at at A and then proceed to B as a freah dataset

Comment: @rvin Keeping the logic same I have updated the answer to handle groups as well. You can have a look.

Comment: Thanks. But we have more than 1000 groups. Difficult to do manually. The above code is not working as per categories

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `ave`, used to split the data by groups of `Name`.

```
df1$Result <- ave(df1$Price, df1$Name, FUN = function(x){
  y <- rep(NA, length(x))
  z <- 0
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    z <- z + x[i]
    if(z >= 1) {
      y[i] <- z
      z <- 0
    }
  }
  if(z > 0) y[length(x)] <- z
  y
})

df1
#   Name Price Result
#1     A   3.0    3.0
#2     A   0.5     NA
#3     A   0.8    1.3
#4     A   0.1     NA
#5     A   0.1    0.2
#6     B   0.5     NA
#7     B   0.9    1.4
#8     B   1.0    1.0
#9     B   0.4     NA
#10    B   5.0    0.0
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Name  Price  
A      3     
A      0.5
A      0.8   
A      0.1
A      0.1  
B      0.5
B      0.9
B      1 
B      0.4
B      5
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am not able to split by names.

Comment: @rvin I do not understand what you mean. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: Rui, I had edited the data sets. If you look at the 5th row that is for A, the result should be 0.2 because that is the last entry for A and it should not carry for the next category B. Hope you got my point

Comment: @rvin Done. The problem was not the split. There were two problems: 1) you changed the dataset; 2) the last value of each group, in this case `A`, would not have the accumulated sum, only if it was greater than or equal to 1. It is now corrected.

Comment: hi Rui, there is an issue here. if the last entry (say for A is greater than 1), the result is coming as 0, instead of the same logic. For example for A we have 3,0.5,0.8,0.1,3.4, the result should be 3,NA, 1.3,NA, 3.5. In my dataset, the result is coming as 3,NA, 1.3,NA, 0 that is wrong. hope you got my point

Comment: Hi Rui, are you able to get what i am telling :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate data with grouped categorical variables, try `tapply()` or `aggregate()`.

```
Result <- tapply(df$Price, df$Name, function(x){
  temp <- x
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    if(temp[i] < 1){
      temp[i] <- NA
      temp[i + 1] <- x[i + 1] + x[i]
    }
  }
  return(temp)
})

df$Result <- unlist(Result)
df

#    Name Price Result
# 1     A   3.0    3.0
# 2     A   0.5     NA
# 3     A   0.8    1.3
# 4     A   0.1     NA
# 5     A   2.0    2.1
# 6     B   0.5     NA
# 7     B   0.9    1.4
# 8     B   1.0    1.0
# 9     B   0.4     NA
# 10    B   5.0    5.4
```